# Impala streaming over JDBC is really slow

Tags: jdbc, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

I have run several large queries using impala-shell and found the performance to be satisfactory. These queries typically write 100k-1m rows to disk. However, when I run the very same queries programmatically using JDBC, the results take much, much longer to write to disk. For example, a query which takes five minutes from impala-shell takes up to thirty minutes over JDBC.

I have tried both the Hive and Cloudera JDBC drivers but get similarly bad performance. I have tried various fetch sizes but it has not made any difference. Is Impala streaming over JDBC fundamentally slow or could I do something else to speed up the streaming?

This is on CDH 5.9.1.

Comment: What do you mean by "streaming"? Can you show an example of query you are running?

Comment: Basically, if you are running an `INSERT SELECT` query, then the data does *not* transit by your client app, so "fetch size" has no effect. And running 1000 mini-queries in sequence means creating at least 1000 HDFS files (replication x3), which is not the same thing as running one large query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a client-side issue. I was using curl to test a web application which was making the Impala queries. Switching from curl to a client written in Scala code removed the latency.